# htaccess for php api

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure an htaccess file for the first time. I've searched around and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm attempting to do the following:

1 - I would like http://localhost/phpinfo to load phpinfo.php (This works) located in /var/www/phpinfo/php

2 - I would like http://localhost/products to load api/product/read.php (located in /var/www/api/product/read.php) but it returns a 404 - The requested URL /products/ was not found on this server

I'm obviously configuring the .htaccess (located in /var/www/.htaccess) file wrong but have got myself completely confused!

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/phpinfo/$ phpinfo.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/products/$ api/product/read.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Apache.config for AllowOverride

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Any ideas or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :-)

Update taking on board comments (thank you), still no joy :-(

So, now I have modified the .htaccess file as follows. I've moved the phpfile out of the root directory as I thought that might have been giving me a false positive, which it turned out was the case.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?phpinfo/?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/phpinfo.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?products/?$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/product/read.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, neither rewrites are working, I get a 404 for both http://localhost/phpinfo and http://localhost/products.

File structure is now:

/var/www/api/phpinfo.php

/var/www/api/product/read.php (no change from the above but included for reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Above:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

In your .htaccess file.

And delete the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

of the second rule as *products* exists as a *directory* and the following rewrite rule will not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?phpinfo/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /phpinfo.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?products/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/product/read.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Should it have `/api`, rather than `api`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a fair bit of playing around and investigating I got the following to work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "^phpinfo$" "api/phpinfo.php"

RewriteRule "^products$" "api/product/read.php"
```